# $d(f,g)= \sup _{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x)-g'(x)|$ show it is a metric

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ C^1([a,b])$ be the set of real valued continous functions define on $[a,b]$, differentiable with continous derivatives on $[a,b]$

define the function 
  $$ \forall f,g \in  C^1([a,b]) , d(f,g)= \sup _{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x)-g'(x)|$$
where $f'$ denotes the derivative on $f$. Is $d$ a metric on  $C^1([a,b])$

---

The properties of metrics are $\forall f,g,h \in C^1([a,b])$
$$ \begin{aligned}
&(i) && d(f,g) \geq 0
\\&(ii) && d(f,g) =0 \iff f=g
\\&(iii) && d(f,g)=d(g,f)
\\&(iv) && d(f,g) \leq d(f,h)+d(h,g)
\end{aligned}$$

---

**is there something said that is wrong? **

---

**Attempt to show that it is a metric**

***Showing $d(f,g) \geq 0$.***

$f'(x)-g'(x)$ where $x \in [a,b]$ is a real number so the absolute value of it is greater or equal to $0$.

[**showing ii**]

$(d(f,g)=0 \Rightarrow f=g)$

assuming that $$d(f,g)=\sup |f'(x)-g'(x)|=0$$
so $\forall x \in [a,b]$ 
       $$ f'(x)-g'(x)=0  \equiv f'(x)=g'(x)$$
integrating we have that 
$$\int f'(x)dx =\int g'(x)dx \Rightarrow f(x)=g(x)$$

($\Leftarrow ] $ $f=g \Rightarrow d(f,g)=0$ )

So $\forall x\in [a,b]$ $f(x)=g(x)$ so differentiating we have that $$f'(x)=g'(x) \Rightarrow f'(x)-g'(x)=0$$ so $\forall x \in [a,b]$ 
$$\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f'(x)-g'(x)|=0 $$

**Showing** $d(f,g)=d(g,f)$
$$\begin{aligned}
d(f,g)&=\sup _{x \in[a,b]} |f'(x)-g'(x)|
  \\ & =   \sup _{x \in[a,b]} |g'(x)-f'(x)|
\\ &=d(g,f)
\end{aligned} $$

Showing **Triangular inequality** ($d(f,g)\leq d(f,h)+d(h,f)$)

$$\begin{aligned}
d(f,g)&=\sup_{x\in[a,b]} |f'(x)-g'(x)|
\\&=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f'(x)-h'(x)+h'(x)-g'(x)|
\end{aligned} $$

call sup to be $x_1$ so 
$$ |f'(x_1)-h'(x_1)+h'(x_1)-g'(x_1)| \leq  |f'(x_1)-h'(x_1)|+|h'(x_1)-g'(x_1)|$$
Now $x_1$ may not be the sup of each absolute diff of 2 functions  so

$$  |f'(x_1)-h'(x_1)|+|h'(x_1)-g'(x_1)|
  \leq \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x_1)-h'(x_1)|+  \sup_{x \in [a,b]}|h'(x_1)-g'(x_1)|=d(f,h)+ d(h,g)$$
$\therefore d(f,g) \geq d(f,h)+d(h,g)$

**We have that the 4 prop of metrics do hold $\therefore$ $d$ is a metric**

Comment: It's not a metric. Let $f(x) = 1, g(x) = 2$.

Comment: $d(f,g)=0\implies f-g=\text{constant}$

Comment: If $f$ and &g$ differ by a constant, $d(f,g) =0$ but $f \neq g$

Comment: Some "cheaty" to prove that it is a metric: Let $D:C^1[a,b]\to C^0[a,b]$ be given by $D(f)=f'$. Then $d(f,g)=d_\infty(Df,Dg)$, where $d_\infty(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)|$ is the usual uniform metric. It is a general fact that a metric defined such as $d$ (in terms of some function and a metric on the range) is a pseudometric, and a metric iff the function $D$ is injective, which is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False.  Try the constant functions $f(x) = 0, g(x) = 1$.